# Github failing to add arbitrary .svg file?

Tags: git, github, svg

I'm a little new to github and I have no idea why it isn't adding some SVG files. They're absolutely standard SVG files and the only indication of anything possible wrong with them is this small icon at the end of each file in the Github UI:

[image]

I have a feeling it's something to do with no newline at end of file but as I'd said I'm a beginner and I'd have no idea how to go about fixing it even if I knew for sure (I've tried saving the files with a new line at the end).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813311/no-newline-at-end-of-file.