# What is little red arrow and no sign in github desktop?

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

What does this little arrow and "no" symbol to the right of "get_footer(); ?>" mean?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: My best guess is that it means the file lacks a trailing newline

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's [the `no-newline` octicon](https://octicons.github.com/icon/no-newline/). It tells you that your file doesn't have a trailing newline.

You can read about why that is important to note in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5813359/641451).

Comment: thank you, wish there was a tooltip for that in github desktop

Comment: You can try [contacting GitHub](https://github.com/contact) about that - they tend to appreciate nice ideas.