# Red circle with slash through it and carriage return symbol in pull request changes on github

Tags: github, ros, line-endings

In the list of changed files for a pull request on github, a couple of files have this symbol at the end of the file:

[image]

Both are in the format of:

```
foo
bar
etc
---
```

They are [ROS `.srv`](http://wiki.ros.org/srv#Service_Description_Specification) files with an empty response (which is [allowed](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/std_srvs/html/srv/Empty.html)). Is this github thinking the file *should* end in a newline? I've never seen this symbol before.

Comment: That seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/34273643/6309

Comment: @VonC. I'll mark this as a duplicate. Half the battle was even knowing how to describe it. That's definitely it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You are most welcome. As requested, I have closed this question as duplicate.