# How to re-write json to a file so as not to get "\ No newline at end of file" diff against npm generated package.json

Tags: json, node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I have a `nodejs` project.
Where i have few dependencies in package.json

in the "scripts" section i have added `"preinstall":"node preinstall"`

The `preinstall` script generates the dependencies on the runtime and update package.json, so that can be available for actuall `npm install` call.

`preinstall.js` is something like this

```
const pkg = require('./package.json')
pkg.dependencies['new-package'] = 'latest';
require('fs').writeFileSync('./package.json', JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2))
```

I get an additional diff as below in `package.json`

```
-}
\ No newline at end of file
+}
```

How to get rid of this? I don't want this diff after i write the json file.

Comment: You should: **1.** Manually add a newline to the end of your `package.json` before running your node script as It's good practice to include a trailing new line as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813311/no-newline-at-end-of-file). **2.** Commit that change to git. . **3.** Once you've done that change the `JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2)` part in your node script to `JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2).concat('\n')` - note the addition of `.concat('\n')`. **4.** You should then not see _"No newline ..."_ mentioned in future diffs after your `preinstall` script runs.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the _"No newline..."_ message doesn't seem related to the resultant output from your node script. It's probable that `git diff` will show you this if you were to manually make a change to _package.json_ anyway (i.e. not via the node script). This is simply because your _package.json_ does not initially include a trailing newline character.

Comment: even doing this `require('fs').writeFileSync(JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2)+'\n')` does not help. Don't know why. So i thought to deal with it.

Comment: [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) expects the first argument to be a filename or file descriptor. Your code should be: `require('fs').writeFileSync('./package.json', JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2)+'\n')`. Also did you do points 1 and 2 mentioned in my initial comment?

Comment: oh.. actually i missed that in asking questions.. thanks for pointing. Real code is just way too different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already mentioned by @RobC in the comments, just putting it in an actual answer:

The problem is that `JSON.stringify` correctly adds newline characters on each line, but then fails to insert one on the last line. It results in malformed text files when written to a file (producing `No newline at end of file` warnings etc).

In any case, the solution is to manually add the missing newline by replacing

```
JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2)
```

with

```
JSON.stringify(pkg, null, 2).concat('\n')
```