# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, stringify, oracle-jet

I need some help with this error:

```bash
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
  at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
  at Object.success (dashboard.js:22)
  at fire (jquery-3.3.1.js:3268)
  at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.js:3398)
  at done (jquery-3.3.1.js:9305)
  at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.js:9548)
```

I was trying to transform a string to a JSON object using `JSON.parse()` which caused the above error.
I am using `oracleJet` and this is my code:

```js
function DashboardViewModel() {
      
    var self = this;
    self.lineTypeValue = ko.observable('curved');
    var scatterSeries = []; 
        
    $.getJSON( "http://localhost:8080/points", function (data) {
        console.info(data);
        var ch = '{"name":"graphe1","items":'+JSON.stringify(data.results[1])+ '}';
        console.info(ch);
        console.info(JSON.parse(scatterSeries));
        scatterSeries.push(JSON.parse(ch));           
    });

    /* chart data */
        
    this.scatterSeriesValue = ko.observableArray(scatterSeries);
        
    self.lineTypeOptions = [
        {id: 'straight', label: 'straight'},
        {id: 'curved', label: 'curved'},
        {id: 'stepped', label: 'stepped'},
        {id: 'segmented', label: 'segmented'},
        {id: 'none', label: 'none'}
    ];
}
```

The JSON that I got from `"http://localhost:8080/points"` looked like this:

```json
{
  "results": [
    [
      {
        "b": "0.110547334",
        "cost": "0.000000",
        "w": "1.998889"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 2
      },
      {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 4
      },
      {
        "x": 3,
        "y": 6
      },
      {
        "x": 4,
        "y": 8
      },
      {
        "x": 5,
        "y": 10
      },
      {
        "x": 6,
        "y": 12
      },
      {
        "x": 7,
        "y": 14
      },
      {
        "x": 8,
        "y": 16
      },
      {
        "x": 9,
        "y": 18
      },
      {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 20
      },
      {
        "x": 11,
        "y": 22
      },
      {
        "x": 12,
        "y": 24
      },
      {
        "x": 13,
        "y": 26
      },
      {
        "x": 14,
        "y": 28
      },
      {
        "x": 15,
        "y": 30
      },
      {
        "x": 16,
        "y": 32
      },
      {
        "x": 17,
        "y": 34
      },
      {
        "x": 18,
        "y": 36
      },
      {
        "x": 19,
        "y": 38
      },
      {
        "x": 20,
        "y": 40
      },
      {
        "x": 21,
        "y": 42
      },
      {
        "x": 22,
        "y": 44
      },
      {
        "x": 23,
        "y": 46
      },
      {
        "x": 24,
        "y": 48
      },
      {
        "x": 25,
        "y": 50
      },
      {
        "x": 26,
        "y": 52
      },
      {
        "x": 27,
        "y": 54
      },
      {
        "x": 28,
        "y": 56
      },
      {
        "x": 29,
        "y": 58
      },
      {
        "x": 30,
        "y": 60
      },
      {
        "x": 31,
        "y": 62
      },
      {
        "x": 32,
        "y": 64
      },
      {
        "x": 33,
        "y": 66
      },
      {
        "x": 34,
        "y": 68
      },
      {
        "x": 35,
        "y": 70
      },
      {
        "x": 36,
        "y": 72
      },
      {
        "x": 37,
        "y": 74
      },
      {
        "x": 38,
        "y": 76
      },
      {
        "x": 39,
        "y": 78
      },
      {
        "x": 40,
        "y": 80
      },
      {
        "x": 41,
        "y": 82
      },
      {
        "x": 42,
        "y": 84
      },
      {
        "x": 43,
        "y": 86
      },
      {
        "x": 44,
        "y": 88
      },
      {
        "x": 45,
        "y": 90
      },
      {
        "x": 46,
        "y": 92
      },
      {
        "x": 47,
        "y": 94
      },
      {
        "x": 48,
        "y": 96
      },
      {
        "x": 49,
        "y": 98
      },
      {
        "x": 50,
        "y": 100
      },
      {
        "x": 51,
        "y": 102
      },
      {
        "x": 52,
        "y": 104
      },
      {
        "x": 53,
        "y": 106
      },
      {
        "x": 54,
        "y": 108
      },
      {
        "x": 55,
        "y": 110
      },
      {
        "x": 56,
        "y": 112
      },
      {
        "x": 57,
        "y": 114
      },
      {
        "x": 58,
        "y": 116
      },
      {
        "x": 59,
        "y": 118
      },
      {
        "x": 60,
        "y": 120
      },
      {
        "x": 61,
        "y": 122
      },
      {
        "x": 62,
        "y": 124
      },
      {
        "x": 63,
        "y": 126
      },
      {
        "x": 64,
        "y": 128
      },
      {
        "x": 65,
        "y": 130
      },
      {
        "x": 66,
        "y": 132
      },
      {
        "x": 67,
        "y": 134
      },
      {
        "x": 68,
        "y": 136
      },
      {
        "x": 69,
        "y": 138
      },
      {
        "x": 70,
        "y": 140
      },
      {
        "x": 71,
        "y": 142
      },
      {
        "x": 72,
        "y": 144
      },
      {
        "x": 73,
        "y": 146
      },
      {
        "x": 74,
        "y": 148
      },
      {
        "x": 75,
        "y": 150
      },
      {
        "x": 76,
        "y": 152
      },
      {
        "x": 77,
        "y": 154
      },
      {
        "x": 78,
        "y": 156
      },
      {
        "x": 79,
        "y": 158
      },
      {
        "x": 80,
        "y": 160
      },
      {
        "x": 81,
        "y": 162
      },
      {
        "x": 82,
        "y": 164
      },
      {
        "x": 83,
        "y": 166
      },
      {
        "x": 84,
        "y": 168
      },
      {
        "x": 85,
        "y": 170
      },
      {
        "x": 86,
        "y": 172
      },
      {
        "x": 87,
        "y": 174
      },
      {
        "x": 88,
        "y": 176
      },
      {
        "x": 89,
        "y": 178
      },
      {
        "x": 90,
        "y": 180
      },
      {
        "x": 91,
        "y": 182
      },
      {
        "x": 92,
        "y": 184
      },
      {
        "x": 93,
        "y": 186
      },
      {
        "x": 94,
        "y": 188
      },
      {
        "x": 95,
        "y": 190
      },
      {
        "x": 96,
        "y": 192
      },
      {
        "x": 97,
        "y": 194
      },
      {
        "x": 98,
        "y": 196
      },
      {
        "x": 99,
        "y": 198
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

and I wanted the variable `scatterSeries` to hold a table like this one:

```js
[
  {
    name: "graphe1",
    items: [
      {
        x: 8,
        y: 2
      },
      {
        x: 15,
        y: 15
      },
      {
        x: 25,
        y: 26
      },
      {
        x: 33,
        y: 22
      },
      {
        x: 36,
        y: 40
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I got the string `ch` in the console:

```json
{
  "name": "graphe1",
  "items": [
    {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0
    },
    {
      "x": 1,
      "y": 2
    },
    {
      "x": 2,
      "y": 4
    },
    {
      "x": 3,
      "y": 6
    },
    {
      "x": 4,
      "y": 8
    },
    {
      "x": 5,
      "y": 10
    },
    {
      "x": 6,
      "y": 12
    },
    {
      "x": 7,
      "y": 14
    },
    {
      "x": 8,
      "y": 16
    },
    {
      "x": 9,
      "y": 18
    },
    {
      "x": 10,
      "y": 20
    },
    {
      "x": 11,
      "y": 22
    },
    {
      "x": 12,
      "y": 24
    },
    {
      "x": 13,
      "y": 26
    },
    {
      "x": 14,
      "y": 28
    },
    {
      "x": 15,
      "y": 30
    },
    {
      "x": 16,
      "y": 32
    },
    {
      "x": 17,
      "y": 34
    },
    {
      "x": 18,
      "y": 36
    },
    {
      "x": 19,
      "y": 38
    },
    {
      "x": 20,
      "y": 40
    },
    {
      "x": 21,
      "y": 42
    },
    {
      "x": 22,
      "y": 44
    },
    {
      "x": 23,
      "y": 46
    },
    {
      "x": 24,
      "y": 48
    },
    {
      "x": 25,
      "y": 50
    },
    {
      "x": 26,
      "y": 52
    },
    {
      "x": 27,
      "y": 54
    },
    {
      "x": 28,
      "y": 56
    },
    {
      "x": 29,
      "y": 58
    },
    {
      "x": 30,
      "y": 60
    },
    {
      "x": 31,
      "y": 62
    },
    {
      "x": 32,
      "y": 64
    },
    {
      "x": 33,
      "y": 66
    },
    {
      "x": 34,
      "y": 68
    },
    {
      "x": 35,
      "y": 70
    },
    {
      "x": 36,
      "y": 72
    },
    {
      "x": 37,
      "y": 74
    },
    {
      "x": 38,
      "y": 76
    },
    {
      "x": 39,
      "y": 78
    },
    {
      "x": 40,
      "y": 80
    },
    {
      "x": 41,
      "y": 82
    },
    {
      "x": 42,
      "y": 84
    },
    {
      "x": 43,
      "y": 86
    },
    {
      "x": 44,
      "y": 88
    },
    {
      "x": 45,
      "y": 90
    },
    {
      "x": 46,
      "y": 92
    },
    {
      "x": 47,
      "y": 94
    },
    {
      "x": 48,
      "y": 96
    },
    {
      "x": 49,
      "y": 98
    },
    {
      "x": 50,
      "y": 100
    },
    {
      "x": 51,
      "y": 102
    },
    {
      "x": 52,
      "y": 104
    },
    {
      "x": 53,
      "y": 106
    },
    {
      "x": 54,
      "y": 108
    },
    {
      "x": 55,
      "y": 110
    },
    {
      "x": 56,
      "y": 112
    },
    {
      "x": 57,
      "y": 114
    },
    {
      "x": 58,
      "y": 116
    },
    {
      "x": 59,
      "y": 118
    },
    {
      "x": 60,
      "y": 120
    },
    {
      "x": 61,
      "y": 122
    },
    {
      "x": 62,
      "y": 124
    },
    {
      "x": 63,
      "y": 126
    },
    {
      "x": 64,
      "y": 128
    },
    {
      "x": 65,
      "y": 130
    },
    {
      "x": 66,
      "y": 132
    },
    {
      "x": 67,
      "y": 134
    },
    {
      "x": 68,
      "y": 136
    },
    {
      "x": 69,
      "y": 138
    },
    {
      "x": 70,
      "y": 140
    },
    {
      "x": 71,
      "y": 142
    },
    {
      "x": 72,
      "y": 144
    },
    {
      "x": 73,
      "y": 146
    },
    {
      "x": 74,
      "y": 148
    },
    {
      "x": 75,
      "y": 150
    },
    {
      "x": 76,
      "y": 152
    },
    {
      "x": 77,
      "y": 154
    },
    {
      "x": 78,
      "y": 156
    },
    {
      "x": 79,
      "y": 158
    },
    {
      "x": 80,
      "y": 160
    },
    {
      "x": 81,
      "y": 162
    },
    {
      "x": 82,
      "y": 164
    },
    {
      "x": 83,
      "y": 166
    },
    {
      "x": 84,
      "y": 168
    },
    {
      "x": 85,
      "y": 170
    },
    {
      "x": 86,
      "y": 172
    },
    {
      "x": 87,
      "y": 174
    },
    {
      "x": 88,
      "y": 176
    },
    {
      "x": 89,
      "y": 178
    },
    {
      "x": 90,
      "y": 180
    },
    {
      "x": 91,
      "y": 182
    },
    {
      "x": 92,
      "y": 184
    },
    {
      "x": 93,
      "y": 186
    },
    {
      "x": 94,
      "y": 188
    },
    {
      "x": 95,
      "y": 190
    },
    {
      "x": 96,
      "y": 192
    },
    {
      "x": 97,
      "y": 194
    },
    {
      "x": 98,
      "y": 196
    },
    {
      "x": 99,
      "y": 198
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are calling:

```
JSON.parse(scatterSeries)
```

But when you defined `scatterSeries`, you said:

```
var scatterSeries = [];
```

When you try to parse it as JSON it is converted to a string (`""`), which is empty, so you reach the end of the string before having any of the possible content of a JSON text.

`scatterSeries` is not JSON. Do not try to parse it as JSON.

`data` is not JSON either (`getJSON` will parse it as JSON automatically).

`ch` is JSON … but shouldn't be. You should just create a plain object in the first place:

```
var ch = {
    "name": "graphe1",
    "items": data.results[1]
};

scatterSeries.push(ch);
```

In short, for what you are doing, you shouldn't have `JSON.parse` anywhere in your code. The only place it should be is in the jQuery library itself.

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to debug this same error (I was writing code in TypeScript), but no matter what I did, the error didn't go away, it was really persistent.

I tried to look into the solution in many blogs and also this SO thread. I tried everything and nothing worked out.

Finally, I saw that I created the required file named `products.json` in which I gave a single extra newline (meaning, previously the file had 1 empty line, now it had 2 empty lines) and was following [good GitHub practices as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813311/whats-the-significance-of-the-no-newline-at-end-of-file-log).

Because of that single extra newline in my `products.json` file, I wasted 2 hours fixing a bug that didn't exist in the first place.

Finally when I deleted the entire `products.json` file and re-ran the entire thing, I didn't get any runtime errors and everything was running without any problems.

What I learned by going through all this?
It's that *experience is the teacher of all things.*

Answer (score 3):

Encountered this error in the following function when I tried to pull 'nothing' from LS

Quick fix for posterity

```
const getUserFromLocalStorage = () => {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '');
    } catch (error) {
        return null;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from your code:

```
console.info(JSON.parse(scatterSeries));
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the Json.parse of empty array - scatterSeries , as you doing console log of scatterSeries before pushing ch

```js
var data = { "results":[  
  [  
     {  
        "b":"0.110547334",
        "cost":"0.000000",
        "w":"1.998889"
     }
  ],
  [  
     {  
        "x":0,
        "y":0
     },
     {  
        "x":1,
        "y":2
     },
     {  
        "x":2,
        "y":4
     },
     {  
        "x":3,
        "y":6
     },
     {  
        "x":4,
        "y":8
     },
     {  
        "x":5,
        "y":10
     },
     {  
        "x":6,
        "y":12
     },
     {  
        "x":7,
        "y":14
     },
     {  
        "x":8,
        "y":16
     },
     {  
        "x":9,
        "y":18
     },
     {  
        "x":10,
        "y":20
     },
     {  
        "x":11,
        "y":22
     },
     {  
        "x":12,
        "y":24
     },
     {  
        "x":13,
        "y":26
     },
     {  
        "x":14,
        "y":28
     },
     {  
        "x":15,
        "y":30
     },
     {  
        "x":16,
        "y":32
     },
     {  
        "x":17,
        "y":34
     },
     {  
        "x":18,
        "y":36
     },
     {  
        "x":19,
        "y":38
     },
     {  
        "x":20,
        "y":40
     },
     {  
        "x":21,
        "y":42
     },
     {  
        "x":22,
        "y":44
     },
     {  
        "x":23,
        "y":46
     },
     {  
        "x":24,
        "y":48
     },
     {  
        "x":25,
        "y":50
     },
     {  
        "x":26,
        "y":52
     },
     {  
        "x":27,
        "y":54
     },
     {  
        "x":28,
        "y":56
     },
     {  
        "x":29,
        "y":58
     },
     {  
        "x":30,
        "y":60
     },
     {  
        "x":31,
        "y":62
     },
     {  
        "x":32,
        "y":64
     },
     {  
        "x":33,
        "y":66
     },
     {  
        "x":34,
        "y":68
     },
     {  
        "x":35,
        "y":70
     },
     {  
        "x":36,
        "y":72
     },
     {  
        "x":37,
        "y":74
     },
     {  
        "x":38,
        "y":76
     },
     {  
        "x":39,
        "y":78
     },
     {  
        "x":40,
        "y":80
     },
     {  
        "x":41,
        "y":82
     },
     {  
        "x":42,
        "y":84
     },
     {  
        "x":43,
        "y":86
     },
     {  
        "x":44,
        "y":88
     },
     {  
        "x":45,
        "y":90
     },
     {  
        "x":46,
        "y":92
     },
     {  
        "x":47,
        "y":94
     },
     {  
        "x":48,
        "y":96
     },
     {  
        "x":49,
        "y":98
     },
     {  
        "x":50,
        "y":100
     },
     {  
        "x":51,
        "y":102
     },
     {  
        "x":52,
        "y":104
     },
     {  
        "x":53,
        "y":106
     },
     {  
        "x":54,
        "y":108
     },
     {  
        "x":55,
        "y":110
     },
     {  
        "x":56,
        "y":112
     },
     {  
        "x":57,
        "y":114
     },
     {  
        "x":58,
        "y":116
     },
     {  
        "x":59,
        "y":118
     },
     {  
        "x":60,
        "y":120
     },
     {  
        "x":61,
        "y":122
     },
     {  
        "x":62,
        "y":124
     },
     {  
        "x":63,
        "y":126
     },
     {  
        "x":64,
        "y":128
     },
     {  
        "x":65,
        "y":130
     },
     {  
        "x":66,
        "y":132
     },
     {  
        "x":67,
        "y":134
     },
     {  
        "x":68,
        "y":136
     },
     {  
        "x":69,
        "y":138
     },
     {  
        "x":70,
        "y":140
     },
     {  
        "x":71,
        "y":142
     },
     {  
        "x":72,
        "y":144
     },
     {  
        "x":73,
        "y":146
     },
     {  
        "x":74,
        "y":148
     },
     {  
        "x":75,
        "y":150
     },
     {  
        "x":76,
        "y":152
     },
     {  
        "x":77,
        "y":154
     },
     {  
        "x":78,
        "y":156
     },
     {  
        "x":79,
        "y":158
     },
     {  
        "x":80,
        "y":160
     },
     {  
        "x":81,
        "y":162
     },
     {  
        "x":82,
        "y":164
     },
     {  
        "x":83,
        "y":166
     },
     {  
        "x":84,
        "y":168
     },
     {  
        "x":85,
        "y":170
     },
     {  
        "x":86,
        "y":172
     },
     {  
        "x":87,
        "y":174
     },
     {  
        "x":88,
        "y":176
     },
     {  
        "x":89,
        "y":178
     },
     {  
        "x":90,
        "y":180
     },
     {  
        "x":91,
        "y":182
     },
     {  
        "x":92,
        "y":184
     },
     {  
        "x":93,
        "y":186
     },
     {  
        "x":94,
        "y":188
     },
     {  
        "x":95,
        "y":190
     },
     {  
        "x":96,
        "y":192
     },
     {  
        "x":97,
        "y":194
     },
     {  
        "x":98,
        "y":196
     },
     {  
        "x":99,
        "y":198
     }
  ]]};

var scatterSeries = []; 

var ch = '{"name":"graphe1","items":'+JSON.stringify(data.results[1])+ '}';
               console.info(ch);
               
               scatterSeries.push(JSON.parse(ch));
console.info(scatterSeries);
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GGzZVB

Answer (score 0):

You define `var scatterSeries = [];`, and then try to parse it as a json string at `console.info(JSON.parse(scatterSeries));` which obviously fails. The variable is converted to an empty string, which causes an "unexpected end of input" error when trying to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using .NET 6, the problem was that the controller was declared as `void` and did not return any value.

Simply changing the method declaration to `int` and adding `return 0;` solved this issue for me.

```
[HttpPost]
public int MyMethod(string text)
{
    _logger.Log(text);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because of the data that you are trying to parse is not in a parsable format .
so i suggest to check the data is parsable or not before define the parse.

```
const IsParsable = (data) => {
            try {
                  JSON.parse(data);
                 } catch (e) {
                  return false;
                }
             return true;
    }
        
    var Obj= JSON.stringify({
                "name": "graphe1",
               "items": data.results[1]
     })

    return  IsParsable (Obj) ?  JSON.parse(Obj) : false
```