# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at IncomingMessage.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to make a weather app and I'm using a weather API to get the information but this error shows up when I'm trying to parse the JSON data:
`SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at IncomingMessage.<anonymous>`
edit: I need to get the lat and lon values from an https request. I tried returning it but it will still say lon and lat is undefined.

second edit: If I input the values of lon and lat It will parse the data and send back the JSON but I need the values of lon and lat from the locaionIQ API on the https request. How do I get those values?
here is the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const https = require('https');
const { static, response } = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
  console.log("server is running on port 3000")
})

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html')
})

app.post('/', (req,res)=>{
  
  let apiKeyLocationIQ = process.env.API_KEY_LOCATIONIQ;
  let apiKeyWeather = process.env.API_KEY_WEATHER;
  let cityLocationIQ = req.body.citySearch;
  let urlLocationIQ = "https://api.locationiq.com/v1/search.php?format=JSON&key="+apiKeyLocationIQ+"&q="+cityLocationIQ+"&limit=1";
  https.get(urlLocationIQ, function(response){
    response.on("data",function(data){
      let locationIQ = JSON.parse(data);
      const lat= locationIQ[0].lat;
      const lon= locationIQ[0].lon;
      const cityName = locationIQ[0].display_name;
    })
  })

  let urlWeather = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?&lat='+lat+'&lon='+lon+'&exclude=alerts,minutely&units=metric&appid='+apiKeyWeather+'&lang=en&cnt=7';
  https.get(urlWeather, function(response){
    response.on("data",function(data){
      let weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(weatherData);
      
    })
  })
  
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118396/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-json-input-at-json-parse-anonymous)

Comment: Log if you're getting valid JSON string or not here. `let locationIQ = JSON.parse(data);`. `data` might have already `parsed`.

Comment: Im getting JSON String if Input the lon and lat values on the API URL. but when I try to use the value from the other api it won't work. I tried returning the value but still the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Node, `HTTP/HTTPS` request data can arrive in multiple chunks which need to be amalgamated before parsing the resultant JSON string.

Essentially JSON parsing needs to be performed in an `on("end", callback)`, not in an `on("data", callback)`, or risk incomplete JSON text.

Node documentation has an excellent working example for getting JSON data under [http.get(options[, callback])](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback). This does not appear to be duplicated in the HTTPS section of documentation due to similarities of the `HTTP` and `HTTPS` APIs.

Comment: im sorry im very new to programming but may I know what I should do? what should I change? I tried changing the response.on to 'end' but its still the same

Comment: @CloydAbad Adapt the linked example to suite your needs in terms of getting JSON data. For example you can't omit the `on(data, callcack)` processing to concatenate arriving data. Waiting for both API calls to complete before responding to the request will also be necessary. This may require nested callback  requests or promisifying `https.get` using (`util.promisify(original)`)[https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback] or similar. The `await` operator is often useful when it comes to processing results.

Comment: hey man sorry it took so long for me to reply hehe, anyway I learned asyn await last week and I finall understand what youre saying, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Https response data are collected in small chunks, so when its collecting data ("on"), we should append the data(string) in variable (starting with empty string [here let chunks="";])

When all the chunks of data are collected ("end"), then we should finally parse the string(API data) into JSON format.

```
https.get(apiLink, function (response) { 

        let chunks="";
        response.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks+=chunk;
        });
        response.on("end", function(){
            // console.log("API Data recieved");

            let defaultCovidData = JSON.parse(chunks);
            // code after parse string into JSON format
        });

});
```