# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input -- NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, jsonparser

When trying to load a json file and load it into an object called players I get an error and the server stops, does anyone know why?
The code;

```
function getjson(){
        fs.readFile('./src/player.json', 'utf8', (err, jsonString) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("File read failed:", err)
                return
            }else{
                players = JSON.parse(jsonString);
            }
        })
    }
```

The error;

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118396/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-json-input-at-json-parse-anonymous) answer your question?

Comment: Lets see the content of `jsonString`

Comment: definitely something wrong inside jsonString