# How can I fix this ajax error on the developer console log

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, laravel

I am new to ajax and I am creating a Laravel Crud application. In one modal I get the "uncaught syntaxerror:" message in the console when I click on the edit button to save the changes in the modal. Can any one assist with the issue. I will be very grateful.

[image]

Comment: you should add some code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118396/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-json-input-at-json-parse-anonymous)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.