# Avoid "No newline at end of file" in git diff

Tags: git, line-endings, gitattributes, lf

I'm quite sure I understand what [No newline at end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813311/no-newline-at-end-of-file) means. I want to provide a pull request of a branch which I created long time ago and rebased (commits might be from the time before `.gitattributes` has been added). I see that some `.java` source code files have only the change

```
-}
\ No newline at end of file
+}
```

regardless of the configuration, I'd simply like these changes to be excluded from the PR commit. I'd like to avoid picking the changes with `git difftool` and broaden my understanding of `git`.

The thing is that I already don't understand how this change can exist since there's a `.gitattributes` with

```
# Set the default behavior, in case people don't have core.autocrlf set.
* text=auto

# Explicitly declare text files you want to always be normalized and converted
# to native line endings on checkout.
*.c text
*.h text
*.java text
*.css text
*.js text
*.xml text
*.dtd text
*.xsl text
*.properties text
*.txt text
*.svg text
*.yml text
*.md text

# Declare files that will always have CRLF line endings on checkout.
*.sln text eol=crlf

# Denote all files that are truly binary and should not be modified.
*.png binary
*.gif binary
*.jpg binary
*.jpeg binary
*.eot binary
*.ttf binary
*.woff binary
*.woff2 binary
```

in the repository and I ran `git rm --cached -r . && git add .` which should convert all line endings to LF because of `*.java text` (also tried `*.java text`), but there're no changes shown (against `HEAD`) and `git diff` still shows the line ending difference.

Also `find ./ -type f -name '*.java' -exec dos2unix {} \;` doesn't causes any changes to be recognized by `git status` and `git diff master` still displays the line ending change (while the working directory has no staged or unstaged changes).

I'm not interested in hiding the changes, like `git diff --ignore-all-space` would do.

I'm using `git` 2.17.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

> The thing is that I already don't understand how this change can exist ...

The change shows that the `a/` version of the `whatever.java` file is missing a newline, while the `b/` version of the file has one.  "Missing a newline" means that the file ends with *no* line terminator—it's not a question of CRLF vs LF, it's a question of "has terminator" vs "does not have terminator".

Some editors are capable of handling files that have a final line that lacks a terminator.  Other editors are not and don't even notice that there is one missing (mostly just pretending there was one).  Some editors will default to adding a terminator if it seems appropriate, perhaps with a warning.  There is a lot of variation here.

You don't show what particular `git diff` command (with what options) generated the diff, so it's hard to say where the `a/` and `b/` versions came from, but I'll assume `HEAD` commit and either-`index`-or-work-tree below.  (That is, we're looking at trimmed `git diff --cached` or `git diff HEAD` output.  Either way we'll see the same thing since `git diff` has to run the work-tree file through any `clean` filter and any end-of-line filtering.)

> ... since there's a `.gitattributes` [that includes]
>
> ```
> *.java text
> ```
>
> ... and I ran `git rm --cached -r . && git add .` which should convert all line endings to LF ...

This will convert any existing CRLF line endings in the work-tree to LF-only line endings in the index.  I do not believe it will an add LF-ending to lines that have no ending at all (based on the code in [`crlf_to_git` in `convert.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7e8bfb0412581daf8f3c89909f1d37844e8610dd/convert.c#L505)).

So, that suggests that your work-tree copy of the file has a final CRLF as the last two bytes of the file, or a final LF-only newline byte as the last single byte of the file.  Git would `git add` that as a final newline.  Meanwhile, if the commit itself has a lone close-curly brace (with *no* line endings at all, neither CRLF nor newlne) as its final byte, that means that the committed (`HEAD`) copy of the file differs from the index version of the same file by having the committed copy lack any line terminator at all, and you'd see just what you do see.

Answer (score 3):

Issue:  \ No newline at end of file

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/abc.txt b/abc.txt
index 5996e61..6a3c3a9 100644
--- a/abc.txt
+++ b/abc.txt
{
+  **Actual change**
FR(srctxt,reptxt,fname)
else:
-    os._exit(1)
\ No newline at end of file
+    os._exit(1)
```

**Solution:**
Remove the last line and append the same line without newline using **echo -n "APPEND LAST LINE TEXT AFTER REMOVING THE LAST LINE TEXT" >>abc.txt**

```
$ **echo -n "    os._exit(1)" >> abc.txt**

$ **git diff**
diff --git a/abc.txt b/abc.txt
index 5996e61..f2b2e74 100644
--- a/abc.txt
+++ b/abc.txt
@@ -419,6 +419,7 @@ EStatus 
{
+  **Actual change**
FR(srctxt,reptxt,fname)
```