# I do not understand the diff in files using git diff

Tags: git

I ran git diff between files with same name but with different branches. And I got this diff:

[image]

I do not understand the diff. They look the same to me. This is at the last line of the file. What is the difference here? Both files do not have newline at the end.

Comment: Are there any whitespace changes between the lines? Are you positive both commits do not have newlines at the end of the file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813311/no-newline-at-end-of-file

Comment: "*Both files do not have newline at the end.*". No, one has and the other doesn't, so the difference.

Comment: More specifically, the old version of the file ends with the close square bracket and newline, and the new version of the file ends with the close square bracket but no newline. The `\ No newline at end of file` line comes right after whichever file *doesn't* have the final newline.

Comment: You guys are correct the old one had a new line. The new one didn't. I got confused by the +] and -].. If you guys post your comments as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Better to mark it as a dupe: [No newline at end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813311/no-newline-at-end-of-file)

Comment: Don't think its a duplicate. The other question asks what's the issue with "No newline at the end of file". My question is I couldn't understand the diff itself..