# Github New line missing end of file: Negative consequences

Tags: github, yaml, swagger

We have a Java code pull request with Swagger. It's missing the new line character in end of YAML file. What are the consequences of not having new line character?

Curious if we should enforce policy at company, too many people are forgetting to do this. Takes lot of time, however researching how it effects our codebase/system.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main consequence is regarding `git diff`: when you are diffing files, not having a newline at the end can result in misleading diffs. Tools like `git` will show changes in lines that have not fundamentally changed, just because a newline was added.
Not having a newline can sometimes increase the likelihood of encountering merge conflicts.

See more at "[What's the significance of the "No newline at end of file" log?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5813311/6309)".

Other consequences:

- Some tools expect a newline at the end of files and may not behave as expected if a newline is missing. That could include text editors, compilers, and others.
- Certain YAML parsers may expect files to end with a newline and may throw errors or behave unexpectedly if a newline is missing.

Plus, regarding the code style, not having a newline at the end of a file can sometimes make code less readable, as it can result in the last line of code being "joined" with the command prompt in terminal-based text editors.

---

You can enforce it:

- from the client side:

  - IDE: integrated development environments (IDEs) and text editors have settings that can be configured to automatically add a newline at the end of files upon saving, which can help to enforce this policy without requiring additional effort from developers. It can be a good practice to encourage developers to configure their development environments to automatically add a newline at the end of files to avoid these potential issues.
  - [content filter driver "smudge"](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_filter), with a `*.yaml filter=ensure_newline` in the `.gitattributes`, and local activation of that filter with `git config filter."encure_newline".smudge /path/to/your/ensure-newline.sh` + `git config filter."encure_newline".clean cat`: I prefer it to a pre-commit hook which would have a harder time to be limited to `*.yaml` file, and would only reject the commit (as opposed to add the missing trailing newline).

Regarding the last option, the `ensure-newline.sh` script would be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the file ends with a newline, and if not, add one
if [ "$(tail -c1)" != "" ]; then
    echo ""
fi

# Pass the file contents through unchanged
cat
```

- from the server side

  - [pre-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_pre_receive), to prevent pushing a commit with the wrong content
  - a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions), preventing any PR to be merged with the wrong content.

For the pre-receive hook, the script would be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Iterate over every ref being pushed
while read oldrev newrev refname; do
  # Get the list of files in the push
  files_in_push=$(git diff --name-only $oldrev $newrev)

  # Check each file in the push
  for file in $files_in_push; do
    # If the file ends with .yaml, check if it ends with a newline
    if [[ $file == *.yaml ]]; then
      file_content=$(git show $newrev:$file)
      
      # If the file does not end with a newline, reject the push
      if [[ "$file_content" != *"\n" ]]; then
        echo "Rejected push: $file does not end with a newline."
        exit 1
      fi
    fi
  done
done

# If we reached here, all checks passed
exit 0
```

For the GitHub Action, the `.github/workflows/check_newline.yml` would be:

```yaml
name: Check Newline at EOF

on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - '**.yaml'

jobs:
  check_newline:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        
      - name: Check Newline at EOF
        run: |
          PR_NUMBER=$(echo $GITHUB_REF | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "/" } ; { print $3 }')
          FILES_CHANGED=$(curl -s -X GET -G https://api.github.com/repos/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/pulls/$PR_NUMBER/files | jq -r '.[] | .filename')
          for FILE in $FILES_CHANGED; do
            if [[ "$FILE" == *.yaml ]]; then
              if [ "$(tail -c1 "$FILE")" != "" ]; then
                echo "File $FILE does not end with a newline. Please add a newline at the end of this file."
                exit 1
              fi
            fi
          done
```