# How to make IntelliJ IDEA insert a new line at every end of file?

Tags: intellij-idea, linefeed

How do I make IntelliJ IDEA insert a new line at every end of file, 
so that GitHub doesn't complain for example?

Comment: I'm still having this error even after doing the below for Jupyter Notebooks any one know how to fix it?

Answer (score 644, accepted):

Change your Editor settings:

`Settings` → `Editor` → `General` → `Ensure line feed at file end on Save`

Comment: Is it possible to force only one? I.e. if there is 2 or more it deletes the extra newlines?

Comment: I can't find this setting anymore in Idea 14, is it still possible to do this?

Comment: @mrbrdo In intellij 14 it's ```Settings->Editor->General->Other->Ensure line feed at file end on save.```

Comment: It adds new line but the message is still there.(I am on Windows and use Checkstyle InteliJ plugin).

Comment: @Xelian If the line is there, then there are bugs in the tools that highlight there isn't a new line.

Comment: Is it possible to get IntelliJ IDEA to add a new line at the end of generated files as well?
I'm having issues with TypeScript adding the sourceMap reference at the last line of JS files and not adding a new line after it.

Comment: the setting has moved in newer version:
Settings -> Editor -> General -> Ensure line feed at file end on save

Comment: @NightRa Why do we want to have new line at the end of a file? Is this some standard or smth?

Comment: Since IntelliJ auto-saves, I don't get the new line unless I explicitly save the file. This doesn't quite solve it for me unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun I think this is \*nix-specific (like macOS and Linux), not the case in Windows. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline): "...newlines either *separate* lines or that they *terminate* lines." In \*nix system they terminate lines, so it appears to some programs that there is a trailing blank line.

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun, here is some more elaborated answers to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4700312/369824

Answer (score 115):

For MAC users:

`Preferences > Editor > General > Ensure every saved file ends with a line break`

Comment: I want something similar, but **for the first-line**, is there any way? Currently the IDE does the opposite (and auto deletes empty lines from begin of file).

Answer (score 55):

Possible alternative with a number of handy features is [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/)

Just submit an `.editorconfig` file to your repo

```
[*]
insert_final_newline = true
```

And it will work natively not only in Idea, but in all major IDEs (some require a plugin).

Now all team members would have same configuration, eol, eof, and no more tabs vs spaces :)

Comment: In WebStorm this will override the default IDE configuration if plugin enabled.

Comment: Wow! Really like this answer. The new line before EOF is such a small details sometimes is not worth to explain to other people in the team who don't understand and don't care about it. This should be the answer of choice because. Other answers are more likely to be out of date when JetBrains rearrange the UI. This answer is more likely to be valid for good as EditorConfig is enabled by default on Intellij.

Comment: Note that in Android Studio it'll add a new line when you save any change, not on reformatting

Comment: @Maragues autosave for the rescue!

Comment: Great, tested with phpstorm (2019.2.1), after update.

Comment: I think the posted code snippet of the .editorconfig shall have an additional linefeed at the end.

Answer (score 51):

### IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3

#### Approach 1

**File** > **Settings...** > **Editor** > **General** > **Ensure line feed at file end on Save**

[image: File > Settings]

[image: Editor > General > Ensure]

#### Approach 2

**Help** > **Find Action...** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) > type "**Ensure line feed**" > switch the toggle to **ON** (using the mouse click or <kbd>Enter</kbd>) for "Other: Ensure line feed at file end on Save" line

[image: Help > Find Action]

[image: Ensure line feed]

Answer (score 25):

For Mac Users: IntelliJ Idea version 2020.2

**Option1:**

IntelliJ Idea -> Preferences -> General -> Ensure an empty line at the end of a file on save
[image]

**Option2:**

⬆️ + ⌘ + A or Or just click on Help from menu bar -> Find Action and then type Ensu and choose Ensure an empty line at the end of a file on save
[image]

Comment: In current version (2021.1) it is called `"Ensure every saved file ends with a line break"`

Comment: I was wondering about that. To me a "line break" did not necessarily equate to an extra line at the end of the file.

Comment: did not work for me - even though the option is checked, no new line gets inserted on save

Answer (score 6):

General -> Save Files For IntelliJ IDEA 2020.

Check the Bottom Right Corner:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

In latest versions of IntelliJ, the setting has been renamed to 'Ensure an empty line at the end of a file on save', and it has been moved under Setting>Editor>General>Save Files

[image]

This should have been a comment, but I wanted to add the screenshot as well so wrote as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

As Rider (IDEA's cousin for .NET) is driving me crazy, this might be helpful for those writing C# as `Ensure line feed at file end on Save` alone won't work. It needs

`File → Settings → Editor → Code Style → C# → Line Breaks and Wrapping → Line feed at end of file`.

I don't remember changing it and I haven't imported any settings for sure, so I guess it's by default disabled.

[image: Rider settings]

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was going crazy trying to get this to work right.

Answer (score 4):

With the Intellij version 2022.3.1

Preferences (`cmd + ,`) > Editor > General > **Ensure every saved file ends with a line break**

Check, apply, and click ok

[intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSE5X.png)

Answer (score 1):

With the IntelliJ Idea version 2020.3:
Go to File > Sttings > Editor > General > On Save

And then select/deselect "Ensure every saved file ends with a line break"

[image]