# ESLint: Insert `⏎` (prettier/prettier) error in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, eslint

On every time on file save ESLint gives this error:

`ESLint: Insert` ⏎ `(prettier/prettier)`

When I add new line, it remove it and still shows this error.

How can I prevent this ESLint error in WebStorm?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent it on intellij (Web Storm etc), set editor config to add new line at the end of all files.

You can set this:
`Settings → Editor → General → Ensure line feed at file end on Save`

More detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16761228/134739